# Nested loop in managing two files PYTHON

Tags: python

Tonight I have a problem with creating file from two files. I would like to achieve text file which will contain 3 first columns from first file and two 2 columns from the second file. Till now i have done good reading and concatenating for this files but finally i achieve not every lines but just one concatenated in a right way. :(

Files have structure presented below: 
File1:

```
DATA1 DATA2 data3 ...... 
DATA1 DATA2 data3 ......
```

File2:

```
DATA1 DATA2 data3' data4 ....
DATA1 DATA2 data3' data4 ....
```

outputfile:

```
DATA1 DATA2 data3 data3' data4
DATA1 DATA2 data3 data3' data4
```

As I Said right now I achieved only one row in right way not every . FILE 1 AND FILE 2 haven't got the same amount of rows. DATA1 and DATA2 in both input files have to be the same. 
Problem is somewhere in for loop because i cannot acheive the full file :(
I will be ver very gratefull for error correction of my code

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
finalfile =  None
for line in file1:
    row1 = line.rstrip().split()
    first_column1 = row1[0]
    second_column1 = row1[1]
    #print(str(first_two_columns1)+ " "+ str(first_three_columns1)+ "\n")
    for line in file2:
        row2 = line.rstrip().split()
        first_column2 = row2[0]
        second_column2 = row2[1]
        #print(str(first_two_columns1)+ " "+ str(first_two_columns2)+ "\n")
        if(float(first_column1) == float(first_column2)) and (second_column1 == second_column2):
            rows = row1[0] + " " + row1[1] + " " + row1[2] + " " + row2[2] + " " + row2[3] + "\n" 
            final_filename = 'final_file_{}.txt'.format(row1[0])
            finalfile = open(final_filename, "w")
        finalfile.write(rows)
if finalfile:
    finalfile.close()
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: Does the output file need to maintain the same order as either of the input files?  How large can the files be?

Comment: no order is not important, this files have max 70 lines each :)

Comment: Will `file1` always be longer than `file2`?

Comment: hmm good question i suppose yes

Comment: For this specific task, nested for loop two read the 2 files is wrong; but if the nested for loop is necessary see [python - Script skips second for loop when reading a file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901909/script-skips-second-for-loop-when-reading-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

If the two files and the output file have the same number of lines, and the task is to merger each corresponding pair of lines form the input files to make each line of the output file, then you don't want nested loops:

```
for line in file1:
    row1 = line.strip().split()
    line = file2.readline()
    row2 = line.strip().split()
    ...
```

From there, you build your output line.

*Update*: If the input files *don't* match up, then you'll need to start reading `file2` from the beginning for each line of `file1`, which you can do by opening/procesing/closing it for each line of `file1`, or use `lseek` to go back to the beginning.  If `file2` isn't too large, you could read its contents into a dictionary, so that you only have to read it once.

Comment: thx but they havent got the same :( this is why i am checking first and second column of each file

Answer (score 0):

I didn't attempt to find where your code went wrong.

First let's start with sorted rows from each file.  Sometimes pre-sorting your data can make things easier later.

```
import csv, operator
# key is a callable that returns
# the first two items in a sequence
key = operator.itemgetter(0,1)

# get a sorted list of rows for each file
with open('file1.csv') as one, open('file2.csv') as two:
    reader = csv.reader(one)
    file_one = sorted(reader, key = key)
    #one = sorted(csv.reader(one), key = key)
    reader = csv.reader(two)
    file_two = sorted(reader, key = key)
    #two = sorted(csv.reader(two), key = key)
```

This assumes there may not be a match and you will need to iterate over `file2` for each line of `file1`.  I've included some inline comments.  This does not need pre-sorted data but can still use it.

```
with open ('out.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for line1 in file_one:
        # find the line in file2 that matches
        for line2 in file_two:
            if line1[:2] == line2[:2]:
                # write the new line to the new file
                out_line = line1[:3] + line2[2:4] 
                writer.writerow(out_line)
                #stop looking in file2
                break
```

**If** you could ensure that there is always a match in `file2`, **Then** you only need to make one pass through each file.  A generator conveniently keeps track of the *`file1`* iteration.  This needs the sorted list of rows for each file defined above.

```
# generator function
def lines(iterable):
    '''yields succesive items from iterable.
    '''
    for item in iterable:
        yield item

with open ('out.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    file_one = lines(file_two)
    for line2 in file_two:
        # find the line in file2 that matches
        try:
            line1 = file_one.next()
            while line1[:2] != line2[:2]:
                line1 = file_one.next()
        except StopIteration:
            # no matching lines in file 2
            error_text = 'file2 does not have a matching line for ' + line1
            raise ValueError(error_text)
        out_line = line1[:3] + line2[2:4] 
        writer.writerow(out_line)
```